# Determine if invoked from webserver

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

What can I call from within Flex/AS3 that will tell me whether the flex-app/web page is being executed within the local file system or rather was served from a webserver (either localhost or some remote server).  Hopefully that's clear.  If there's something in Javascript that's acceptable, but some AS3 function would of course be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Application class has a property: url

url:String  [read-only]

Language Version:       ActionScript 3.0
Product Version:        Flex 4
Runtime Versions:   Flash Player 10, AIR 1.5

The URL from which this Application's SWF file was loaded.

Implementation
public function get url():String

Comment: Thanks.  Used that before. Forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ExternalInterface` to obtain the current URL of the app, and evaluate the string for the scheme:

file:///
http://
https://

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                trace(String(ExternalInterface.call(" function(){ return document.location.href.toString();}")));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Its so weird - I was thinking about that right now - wondering if all browsers would definitely return "file:" if being served as a file.

Comment: Some pure ActionScript test that could validate this from something like flash.system.Capabilities would be nice.  Security policy should also play a role.  Not sure how reliably this implementation will work for you in your environments, but initially seems feasible.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer if nothing better is posted. Guess it wouldn't work if just testing in FlashplayerSA itself.  The reason I need it is because in my experience, an SWFLoader will not work if running as "file:" if trustContent is set to "True".  If there is somewhere to put a crossdomain.xml in the local filesystem that will make it work I have not found it - in C:\ or wherever.  trustContent has to be false or SWFLoader will not run in the local filesystem.  Anyone know what I'm missing there.